# ora-00933 sql command not properly ended delete statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-delete

Getting the following error:

> ora-00933 sql command not properly ended" error Oracle DELETE with JOIN and WHERE SQL statement.

I tried to conditionally delete records from Oracle DB table XEDOCS_LB based on 1st condition from INNER JOIN, and 2nd condition from WHERE as follows:

```
DELETE FROM XEDOCS_LB
INNER JOIN (SELECT ID 
            FROM XEFOLDERS_LB
            WHERE TRANS_TYPE = '80'
              AND TO_DATE(TRUNC(DATEOFUPDATE)) 
                    BETWEEN TO_DATE(SUBSTR('1220430',2,6),'YYMMDD') 
                        AND TO_DATE(SUBSTR('1231231',2,6),'YYMMDD')) XEFOLDERS 
        ON EFOLDERID = XEFOLDERS.ID
WHERE TO_DATE(TRUNC(DATEOFUPDATE)) <= TO_DATE(SUBSTR('1230518',2,6),'YYMMDD')
```

Answer (score 0):

That's invalid syntax in Oracle.

```
delete from xedocs_lb a
where exists (select null 
              from xefolders_lb b
              where b.trans_type = '80'
                and to_date(trunc(b.dateofupdate)) 
                              between to_date(substr('1220430',2,6),'YYMMDD') 
                                  and to_date(substr('1231231',2,6),'YYMMDD')
                and a.efolderid = b.id
             )
  and to_date(trunc(dateofupdate)) <= to_date(substr('1230518',2,6),'YYMMDD');
```

---

On the other hand, maybe you can make it simpler by

- removing `to_date` call on `dateofupdate` column **if** its datatype is `DATE` - probably is, according to `trunc` and later comparison to date values
- removing `to_date(substr(...))` piece of code - why would you use that, if e.g. `1231231` is hardcoded string so you're extracting date from it? Use `date` literal (or `to_date` function with appropriate format model)

So:

```
delete from xedocs_lb a
where exists (select null 
              from xefolders_lb b
              where b.trans_type = '80'
                and trunc(b.dateofupdate) between date '2022-04-30' and date '2023-12-31' 
                and a.efolderid = b.id
             )
  and trunc(a.dateofupdate) <= date '2023-05-18';
```

Comment: I have applied the script above as is and got an error:

Comment: I have applied the script above as is and got an error: "Error: ORA-00904: "B"."EFOLDERID": invalid identifier
 (State:S0022, Native Code: 388)".

Comment: Besides, if I replace DELETE with SELECT in my original script, it works fine, with no errors

Comment: SELECT EFOLDERID
---DELETE 
FROM
  XEDOCS_LB
INNER JOIN
...

Comment: Right; without tables' description, I'm afraid I used columns that belong to different tables. I fixed code; have a look at edited answer, please.